# Revoke parent permissions on child process

Tags: c, linux, fork

I have a context in which for testing and security reason I want to fork a process then revoke the parent's permissions on the child process.

Is there a function to break this parent/child connection when or after forking a process?

Some functions e.g. [`waitpid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/waitpid.3p.html) work only for child processes I want these functions to no longer work on the child process.

Comment: What do you mean by "revoke the parent's permissions on the child process"? What permissions? Do you just want to run the child process totally independent? Why not just `fork` and forget?

Comment: I added an example in `waitpid`.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you wan to solve? While I've added a solution (or a workaround, depending on viewpoint) why do you need to sever the relationship? What are you so worried about would happen if the parent-child relationship is kept? This feels very much like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I'm testing a process waiting on another to exit using `POLLIN` on the file descriptor obtained with `pid_open`, as such I want to prevent `waitpid` working in this circumstance as I want to simulate testing for 2 unrelated processes.

Comment: Well, just don't call `waitpid`? ;) Or do you have other child-processes that you need to reap properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to make the child-processes *orphaned*?

Then use *two* forks: One to create an intermediate child process.

Then the child process does *another* fork for the actual child-process. The intermediate child-process (the direct child) then exits, making the new grand-child process orphaned (its new parent will become the `init` process, with id 1).